# Error While Reading Embedded Resource into byte array (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, resources, embedded-resource

I have an embedded resource named "Test.exe". I want to do the following:

1. Read the contents of Test.exe into a byte array.
2. Write the contents of Test.exe (now in a byte array) to a new location (C:\Test.exe).

I am using the following code (found on this site) - but the problem is that "s" always returns a null value. I am using the below code as follows: `byte[] b = ReadResource("Test.exe");`

```
public static byte[] ReadResource(string resourceName)
{
    using (Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int read = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return ms.ToArray();
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can find what I am having trouble seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full name of the resource. So for example if your application is called `Foo`:

```
byte[] b = ReadResource("Foo.Test.exe");
```

Actually the easiest thing would be to open the assembly with Reflector and look at the exact name of the embedded resource. There might be a namespace in between the name of the application and the name of the resource.

And if you don't have Reflector (yeah it became a paid product), to find out the names of the embedded resources you could use the following code:

```
foreach (var res in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

Once you get the exact name of the embedded resource pass it to the `ReadResource` method.

As yet another alternative you could use [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) and double click on the `MANIFEST` which will show you all embedded resources.

Comment: What is reflector? Is that a 3rd party app?

Comment: You can use ILSpy as a free alternative to reflector.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one line of code if use 'typed' resources.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test1.exe", Resources.TestFile);
```

To add typed resource:

- go to project properties `Resources` tab
- select `File` as resource type
- add your executable file to the resources

  [image]
- now you can reference the file content by `Resources.TestFile`

Comment: That's a great response. Thank you - Just out of curiosity then, why would anybody add an executable file as a resource using any other method if this one is so easy?

Comment: @Evan - hmmm... to make life more difficult I guess :)

Comment: @Evan - so you've chosen to do it the hard way? :)

Comment: Not quite, but he did answer my question that I asked :)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't helpful :(.